# Connectivity between 2 remote Linux machines

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, netstat

I have two remote machines, I'm running a script on one of them.
There's some part of the script that should be running on the other one, then the script will continue in its further tasks/commands.
For some reasons I cannot establish a `ssh-without-password` connection, additionally, I'd not want any password prompts.

N.B: I have shared mount between them.

Comment: try establishing `ssh-without-password` using http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Comment: The thing is, there's one more user that I'll have to be logged in to - which too requires a few digits RSA Passcode - which I want to avoid.

Comment: Why can't you establish an SSH connection with keys? It's the easiest way, and there are very few scenarios in which it wouldn't be possible. If there are additional constraints that prevent this, you need to tell us. The fact that multiple users are involved doesn't make using keys more difficult.

Comment: @Gilles You're right, but its a script so even if I use Keys/passcode I wonder how the script'd be able to Continue its further execution(like how do you let the script know that the login was successful, continue further), is it possible?

Comment: It's easier with keys than with a password: the script just does `ssh remotehost somecommand`, whereas a password requires an additional layer because SSH has no way to provide a password except interactively. I don't understand why you think that keys would introduce a difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid SSH password promts:

`sudo apt-get install sshpass`

*An alternative tool for package installation is `dpkg`*

*[download the `sshpass` deb packet](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=sshpass)*

*and install it:*

*`sudo dpkg -i sshpass_1.04-1_amd64.deb`*

pattern to use as follows:

`sshpass -p mypassword ssh user@server`

if needed to avoid `sudo` password promt:

`ssh uder@server-abc.com "echo sudo_password | sudo -S ./script.sh"`

The explanation for the last one is:  having `sudo` run after ssh, it never gets a password input for `sudo` on the remote server, so the solution is use -S and pipe a password for sudo as above.

Comment: Any alternative for apt-get?, It wouldn't work on my GNU/Linux.

Comment: @Keys I added a bit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a passwordless login you should create an `SSH Keygen`.

For more information on the subject and how to do it see :

[https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys.](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Comment: I've tried ssh Keygen & ssh-copy-id to my destination server, it didn't work :(

Comment: @Keys have you used ssh-keygen for the same user your script will use?

Comment: Have tried for another user - the first level, if that succeeds then would need to find a way for another user(the second level) which then'd follow the same thing(password-less login), if at all possible(!), any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

a.First log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys

b.Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already exist, which is fine)

```
ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
```

b@B's password

c. Finally append a's new public key to b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last time:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

b@B's password:
d. ssh b@B
Now you don't need to enter the password of B server.